# Why is my Table of Contents created empty in OpenOffice/LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer, word-processing, libreoffice, table-of-contents

I have a document and I would like to create a Table of Content.

I tried with **Insert > Indexes and Tables > Indexes and Tables...** and added a title, then I pressed **OK**.

But I only got a **title** and no Table of Content.

How do I add my headlines to the Table of Content? Should they be added automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [OpenOffice wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Creating_a_table_of_contents) every item which you want to see in the Table of Content must be styled as heading. So change style of titles of paragraphs to heading (1,2,3 etc.) and you will see them in the Table of Content.
Then right-click on the Table of Content and select Update Index/Table from the pop-up menu.

Comment: Ok, but how can I see what "style" my titles has, and how do I change them to be "heading (1,2,3 etc.)?

Comment: I read about how to applying styles, that helped. Thanks. http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Applying_styles

Comment: Tried this in LibreOffice Writer, but did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is a bug on Google Docs. All the downloaded ODTs lack of the relation between the outline and the headings styles. [Here is a similar question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/91168/empty-table-of-contents-even-thought-i-set-all-the-headings-correctly/). Therefore, you have to fix the issue:

1. Go to **Tools > Chapter Numbering...** (*Outline Numbering* on older versions), and select the paragraph style (probably "Heading 1" for Level 1 and so on... up to level 6.

   [image: screenshot]
2. Then update the ToC:

   [image: screenshot]

**Update**: It seems [fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJBfk.png) on newer versions (6.0+).

Comment: As of Libre Office 5.3.6.1 (November 2017), this is still good and useful advice. Without it, Tables of Contents do not appear until you associate Level 1 with the Heading 1 Paragraph Style, as shown above. The only thing I'd add is that once you've done this, you just need to return to your ToC, right click, and choose Update Index (even though it's a ToC). You should then see your paragraph and chapter headings.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. I added your suggestion with a screenshot. Please upvote if you find this answer useful.

Comment: Still the same issue in Version: 6.0.7.3. In addition, to refresh the ToC I have to go in: Tools > Update > Update All. Btw, thanks for the Chapter **numbering** trick, I was unable to figure out where the hell was the *Outline numbering* because it simply doesn't exist on this version!